# best practice to manage an EventAggregate when a form is disposed

Tags: c#, winforms, eventaggregator

a conceptual question for you:

I've implemented a Winform program that heavily uses multithread (await/async) and is based on a MDI form that had a docking control and lot of window that can be opened/closed. Some of them are just hidden on close, while others are disposed

I started creating my business classes exposing vanilla events, but soon i realized i was going to have nightmares because of memory leak (remember to remove every subscribed events to other componet when closing forms, etc...) and i implemented a better solution using a custom Event Aggregator

such Event Aggregator uses WeakReference, so that i thought i didn't had to remember to clean every aggregated event subscriber, the problem is that when i close my forms (and they get disposed), the WeakReference still shows that those forms are Alive, that's because the Forms aren't yet GarbageCollected, this cause the problem that the subscribers still can receive events published.

Now i'm wondering what's the best way to handle such problem, currently my choices are:

1. when in my EventAggregate i notify an event, i could check if the receiver is IDisposable and check if it's a System.Windows.Forms.Control and then check its "IsDisposed"/"IsDisposing" properties
2. in every event handler check if the form is disposed/disposing, to prevent doing stuffs on a disposed object
3. override OnDispose on every Form and force GC.Collect so that my weakreference signals that subscriber as dead
4. override OnDispose on every Form and unregister any subscription my form has done

1 and 2 are ugly, 3 and 4 are better but I hope i miss some other way to accomplish this in a better way, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The prefered way (IMHO) would be a variation on #4, instead of using `OnDispose()` use [`OnFormClosed()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosed(v=vs.110).aspx) it is a little more reliable just in case your caller closed the forum but never disposed it.

```
protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     UnregiesterEvents();
     base.OnFormClosed(e);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, using OnFormClosed for forms probably is better, (but i need it even for other kind of controls that don't have that method). Anyway this doesn't improve my options so I still hope for other solutions (if any)